# access selected option of dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a little JS function that is checking the value of input fields and puts them on the form:

```
function insertText()
{
result = document.new_link['link[link]'].value;
document.getElementById("link-link").innerHTML=result;
}
```

which works superb. (new_link is the name of the form)

Now I'm doing the same with a select dropdown menue:

```
<select name="link[link_category]">
<option value="1">Something</option>
</select>


function insertText2()
{
result = document.new_link['link[link_category]'].value;
document.getElementById("link-category").innerHTML=result;
}
```

The result here is the value "1" which I don't like. I want the output "Something" so exactly what is the option's content when it is selected.

I tried this:

```
function insertText2()
{
result = document.new_link['link[link_category]'].content;
document.getElementById("link-category").innerHTML=result;
}
```

but it gives me the output "undefined". I also tried "text" but with no success.
What do I need to do to reach my goal?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should probably use innerText or textContent, depending on what browsers you'd like to support, and you have to target the actual option that is selected, not the select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
function insertText2()
{
   var dropdown = document.new_link['link[link_category]'];
   var selOption = dropdown[dropdown.selectedIndex];
   document.getElementById("link-category").innerHTML=selOption.innerHTML;
}
```

So you grab the drop down element. Then find out the selected index and use that to grab the actual selected option. Once you've got that you can just display the innerHTML which should be the value you're after.

Comment: Works life a charm!
Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You could put the "Something" in as the value. Is there a reason you have used "1" here?

```
<select name="link[link_category]">
    <option value="Something">Something</option>
</select>
```

The individual option elements are available as an HTMLCollection:

```
document.new_link['link[link_category]'].childNodes
    OR
document.new_link['link[link_category]'].options
```

The currently selected option is available as an index:

```
document.new_link['link[link_category]'].selectedIndex
```

The "label" of the selected option can be found at:

```
var selectElement = document.new_link['link[link_category]'];
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```